# get clicked event of tool-tip button google charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I want a button to call a function onclick but it does not. I tried ng-click which does not work. But when I try onclick it says my function is undefined. How can I accomplish that?[image]

Thank you.

Function to customize the tooltip:

```
function createCustomHTMLContent(img, evtTime, cmname, evt, cust, serv, descr, duration) {


  var html ='<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script><div class="myclass" style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;width: 300px;height: 350px;">' +
    '<img src="'+img+'" style="width:285px;height:230px">' +
    '<table>'+'<tr>'+
    '<td><strong>Date :</strong></td>' +
    '<td><b>'+evtTime+'</b></td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><strong>Event Type :</strong></td>' +
    '<td><b>'+evt+'</b></td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><strong>Customer :</strong></td>' +
    '<td><b>'+cust+'</b></td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><strong>Severity :</strong></td>' +
    '<td><b>'+serv+'</b></td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><strong>Description :</strong></td>' +
    '<td><b>'+descr+'</b></td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
    '<td><form  ng-form-commit name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="testfunt()" target="dummyframe" method="post" novalidate><div class="row"><div class="text-center"><button ng-click="timeline.heyfun();">View Video</button></div></form></div></td></tr></table>';

  return html;

}


function addData() {
    rows.push([""+cmname, ""+id,createCustomHTMLContent(thumbpath,    evtTime, cmname, evt, cust, serv, descr, 0),new Date(datetime), new Date(datetime1),'color:'+colors[serv]]);
    tc.dataTable.addRows(rows);
    var options = {
    width : $scope.width,
    height:  $scope.height,
    title: 'Timeline',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date',
      format:'yy-MM-dd\n\nHH:mm:ss'
    },
    timeline: {  //colorByRowLabel: true,

      showBarLabels: false},
    // backgroundColor: '#ffd',
    colors: grapghcols,
    // This line makes the entire category's tooltip active.
    focusTarget: 'category',
    // Use an HTML tooltip.
    tooltip: { isHtml: true,}
  };

  tc.chart.draw(tc.dataTable, options);
  $compile(tc.dataTable)($scope);
}
```

There is alot of code. SO i tried to include the relevant snippets needed. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to post some code in order to get any help.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the relevant code

Comment: don't see any point using `ng` attributes in tooltip, `onclick` should work, if `timeline.heyfun` is in global scope

Comment: It does not work.it says its undefined

Comment: where is `timeline.heyfun` defined? don't see it here, if it isn't in global scope, it will be `undefined`

Comment: More code definitely required, but specifically, is this in a directive or a controller? I don't see anything to give context as to where this is being run. Makes a difference.